# Dynamically generate method after executing __init__

Tags: python

The objective:
Dynamically generate a method after executing `__init__` variables (the object creation).

First (not dynamical example):

```
string_custom_method='''def custom_method(self):
    print self.text'''

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text='foo'

    exec string_custom_method

Foo().custom_method()
```

This script it is very simple and it works good. The problem is that I actually need to customize the content of `string_custom_method`:

```
string_custom_method='''def custom_method(self):\n'''

def create_custom_method(print_end):
    global string_custom_method
    string_custom_method+='\t'+'print self.text\n'
    if print_end:
        string_custom_method+='\t'+'print "end"'

class Faa:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text='faa'
        create_custom_method(True)

    exec string_custom_method

Faa().custom_method()
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
    def custom_method(self):
                           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

So my conclusion is that python reads the tree of methods before executing `__init__` which is kinda a problem in this case.

After reading some more about this, I thought that maybe by using `staticmethod` like this: `self.custom_method = staticmethod(...)` could work,
but the problem is that `custom_method` it is not defined in the global scope, and I can not define it until `__init__` is executed.

Is there any way of making this work? I know that for this example it does not seems useful but I really need it for my program!

Comment: Would you care to explain your *real* use case instead of this dummy example please ? I think you have a XY problem here - and they certainly are better solutions than using `exec` (hint: 99.9 times out of 100, `exec` and `eval` are the wrong solution).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers the dummy example explains pretty good the problem without posting 100 lines of my program. In my program "custom_method" it is actually and addition of multiple loops with conditions and variables. The conditions and variables are not always useful. It depends of  variables defined by `__init__(self, var1, var2, var3)`. If I remove the un-useful variables and conditions I increment the speed of my loops, which is something I need.

Comment: So why are you writing your code in a way that unnecessary conditions get evaluated at all? There might be any number of solutions for your *actual* problem, maybe subclassing, method extraction, strategy pattern, whatever. But dynamic method creation almost certainly isn't it. I agree with @brunodesthuilliers, this seems to be an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution that precompile the code:

```
funtpl = """
def __TheFunction__(self):
    %s

"""

def create_custom_method(print_end):
    # this would be better done by a template engine I think
    source = ['print self.text']
    if print_end:
        source.append('print "end"')

    source = funtpl % "\n    ".join(source)
    bytecode = compile(source, "<string>", "exec", )
    locals = {}
    eval(bytecode, globals(), locals)
    return locals["__TheFunction__"]



class Faa(object):
    def __init__(self, print_end):
        self.text='faa'
        fun = create_custom_method(print_end) 
        self.custom_method = fun.__get__(self, type(self))

f = Faa(True)
f.custom_method()
```

Good luck running `f.custom_method` thru the step debugger

Answer (score 0):

`__init__()` is called after `exec string_custom_method` line is executed. Class is constructed first, that line is in class scope, so it gets executed while the class itself is being constructed, then python takes the class to create instance, at which point `__init__()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If the motivation for this is that you've got loops executing billions of times, I strongly recommend the [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) jit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll implement it to my solution. It will make it even more faster :)